# Cannot Able to Connect to Dynamo DB with Correct Credentials , Please guide me I am getting Exception through Eclipse (java I am using)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Amazon Sample Code :-

Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered a serious internal problem while trying to communicate with AWS, such as not being able to access the network.

> Error Message: Unable to execute HTTP request:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    init();

```
try {
    String tableName = "my-favorite-movies-table";

    // Create a table with a primary hash key named 'name', which holds a string
    CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest().withTableName(tableName).withKeySchema(new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("name").withKeyType(KeyType.HASH)).withAttributeDefinitions(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("name").withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S)).withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput().withReadCapacityUnits(1L).withWriteCapacityUnits(1L));

    // Create table if it does not exist yet
    TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(dynamoDB, createTableRequest);
    // wait for the table to move into ACTIVE state
    TableUtils.waitUntilActive(dynamoDB, tableName);

} catch(AmazonServiceException ase) {
    System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it " + "to AWS, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.");
    System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
    System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
    System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
    System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
    System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
} catch(AmazonClientException ace) {
    System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered " + "a serious internal problem while trying to communicate with AWS, " + "such as not being able to access the network.");
    System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
}
```

}

Comment: Hey Shwetha, Welcome to Stackoverflow - please show us some of your code and format it as a code block to improve readability. Please also describe what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Maurice ,
it's the sample Code Generated by  AWS .
Please have a look.

Comment: I'd like to, but you haven't actually added it to your question :)